# Why my Pageable API is not working with Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Im implementing an API that is working correctly, but when i use pagitation this is returning nothing.

I have the next code for my repository:

```
public interface VinetaRepository extends JpaRepository<Vineta, Long> {
List<Vineta> findAllByOrderByCreationdateDesc();
List<Vineta> findByTitulo(String titulo);}
```

and, when i used the next RequestMapping everthings is ok:

```
@JsonView(VinetaView.class)
@RequestMapping("/api/vinetas2/")
public List<Vineta> getvinetas2(){
    return this.vinetarepository.findAll();
}
```

but, when i use the pagination, my api is returnin anything:

```
@JsonView(VinetaView.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/vinetaspage/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Vineta> getvinetaspage(Pageable page ){
    //This System.out print all the size of my repository
    System.out.println(this.vinetarepository.findAll().size());
    //This for print the title for my 20 first objects Vineta
    for(Vineta v:this.vinetarepository.findAll(page)){
        System.out.println(v.getTitulo());
    }
    // This print 20
    System.out.println(this.vinetarepository.findAll(page).getSize());
    //This print the page number = 0 
    System.out.println(page.getPageNumber());
    //This print the page size = 20 
    System.out.println(page.getPageSize());

    //Finally, this is not returning nothing
    return vinetarepository.findAll(page);
}
```

With the System out, i can see that the size of my query is correct (20), but nothing is returning.

Both function are using the same Jsonview, so this problem is discarded.

Comment: did you debug the request to check what's in `vinetarepository.findAll(page)`

Comment: I doubt nothing is returned what is your view acting on? The first method returns a `List` the other a `Page` if your view doesn't know how to handle the latter it will return nothing of course.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I'm facing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

An adapter class (like PageWrapper) would be needed to wrap the Spring Data Page interface as the page interface may lack of features.

public class PageWrapper {

}